# Transposing a column and keeping relative values

Tags: excel

I'm learning a lot more about excel and it's pretty fun. I'm hoping I can get some help here. I have a sheet of data that basically looks like this:

[image: Before Image]

What I want to do, is create a cohort-analysis. I want to transpose the years and then have the respective values for each company. Basically, I want my product to look like this:

[image]

You may able to tell that its a cohort-analysis-esque type of table I want this set up for my data so I can produce a graph similar to this:

[image]

So I can see the trend in the cost of deals for each company. I produced these images manually and I dont think it's [time] efficient to do that for a sheet with over 300 rows of data. Any help or guidance would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your Company column fill down so you have a proper data set. Insert a column and use a formula like this starting in b2 `=if(a2>0,a2,b1)`

Then paste that column as values and delete the old one. Now highlight your entire data set and insert a pivot table. After that, make company the rows, year the columns, and cost the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pivot table off your data. First determine the best way to get every row populated with a company name. Then create your pivot table. Play around with the format and desired chart types until it suits your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365.

- Select column 1 and `Fill Down`

  - will copy the company names to each row
- Select the year and Pivot

  - Values column being `Cost of the Deal`
- The generated M-code also shows some setting of data types; renaming column1, etc.

[image]

[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Deal Creation Year", Int64.Type}, {"Cost of deal", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Column1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down", {{"Deal Creation Year", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down", {{"Deal Creation Year", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Deal Creation Year"]), "Deal Creation Year", "Cost of deal", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Column1", "Company"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: I would like to note that the poster is wanting to transform a long form dataset into a short form dataset. Using that terminology may help you find answers that you need in the future. A proper long form dataset has all values filled/repeated in the first column, or any fields which serve as the "identification" values.

Comment: @CourtneyKonieczko Thank you for that terminology. And note that the first step of my suggestion is to fill in the first column appropriately.